# contrib hls js skips parts of the m3u8, howto prevent this

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video.js, http-live-streaming, m3u8

We're working on a server side solution for putting two m3u8 together as one. We've before been using FFMPEG to just concatenate the two streams and create a new one. this all works fine.

However, due to performance issues, we've decided to redesign the implementation by analyzing the original m3u8 files, and concatenating those together as one.

This seems to be working fine, we're able to analyse the original files and rebuild  the m3u8. After this we serve the 'new' m3u8 to the client and everything plays.
We go through the same process for the second m3u8 file, again, everything works, and we're able to play this file as well.

The next thing we try is concatenating the two files to become one. This seems to work just fine, we put the segments after on another and then serve it to the player.
In safari this works like a charm, since we don't need any additional plugins/javascript/etc.

Chrome, using video.js and video-contrib-hls, start to play the stream and seems to work. However, it basically just skips the concatenated stream (which ever one is second). You can see the running time of the movie get shorter and the segments just get ignored by the player.

Is there anyway around this issue?

Below there's a sample part or our concatenated m3u8 (i've changed the url around).

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:5
#EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE:VOD
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:20
#EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME:2016-12-01T18:16:11.743000+00:00
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://localhost/check2?b=123&v=123&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000000
#EXTINF:4.0960,
http://subdomain1.someurl.com/slices/648/456/123/G00000000.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://localhost/check2?b=123&v=123&r=g",IV=0x0000000000000000000000000000000B
#EXTINF:4.0960,
http://subdomain1.someurl.com/slices/648/456/123/G0000000B.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://localhost/check2?b=123&v=123&r=g",IV=0x0000000000000000000000000000000C
#EXTINF:4.0960,
http://subdomain1.someurl.com/slices/648/456/123/G0000000C.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://localhost/check2?b=123&v=123&r=g",IV=0x0000000000000000000000000000000D
#EXTINF:4.0960,
http://subdomain1.someurl.com/slices/648/456/123/G0000000D.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://localhost/check2?b=123&v=123&r=g",IV=0x0000000000000000000000000000000E
#EXTINF:4.0960,
http://subdomain1.someurl.com/slices/648/456/123/G0000000E.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://localhost/check2?b=123&v=123&r=g",IV=0x0000000000000000000000000000000F
#EXTINF:4.0960,
http://subdomain1.someurl.com/slices/648/456/123/G0000000F.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://localhost/check2?b=123&v=123&r=g",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000010
#EXTINF:2.64830,
http://subdomain1.someurl.com/slices/648/456/123/G00000010.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://localhost/check2?b=789&v=789&r=d",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000000
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://subdomain2.someurl.com/slices/4da/456/789/D00000000.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://localhost/check2?b=789&v=789&r=d",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000001
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://subdomain2.someurl.com/slices/4da/456/789/D00000001.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://localhost/check2?b=789&v=789&r=d",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000002
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://subdomain2.someurl.com/slices/4da/456/789/D00000002.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://localhost/check2?b=789&v=789&r=d",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000003
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://subdomain2.someurl.com/slices/4da/456/789/D00000003.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://localhost/check2?b=789&v=789&r=d",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000004
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://subdomain2.someurl.com/slices/4da/456/789/D00000004.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://localhost/check2?b=789&v=789&r=d",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000005
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://subdomain2.someurl.com/slices/4da/456/789/D00000005.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://localhost/check2?b=789&v=789&r=d",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000006
#EXTINF:4.0960,
https://subdomain2.someurl.com/slices/4da/456/789/D00000006.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-KEY:METHOD=AES-128,URI="https://localhost/check2?b=789&v=789&r=d",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000007
#EXTINF:3.09250,
https://subdomain2.someurl.com/slices/4da/456/789/D00000007.ts?x=0&si=0
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

Comment: i've found some debugging info in chrome, seems that the buffers read are incorrent (since it's a second file playing, it restarts at 0)

`00:00:57 466 debug Skipping splice frame generation: first new buffer at 0us begins at or before existing buffer at 0us.
00:00:57 605 info Video codec: avc1.42C00D`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you stitch together two or more streams you need to separate them with the [#EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-20#section-4.3.2.3) tag if there are changes in e,g, the timestamp or tracks. From the spec:

> The EXT-X-DISCONTINUITY tag MUST be present if there is a change in
> any of the following characteristics:

> o  file format

> o  number, type and identifiers of tracks

> o  timestamp sequence